# Audio via PWM pins?

Tags: gpio, pi-4, audio, pwm

Okay, kinda a noob here. I've been looking around, trying to find an answer to playing audio via the PWM pins. I tried rerouting the audio to no avail. I've tried making a script that uses PWM to play audio over the pins. I just can't get it to work at all.

Pi GPIO connections:
Speaker+ on GPIO 18 (PWM 0);
Speaker- on GND

Visual representation (- = speaker negative, + = speaker positive):

```
..-..+..............
....................
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

P.S. Yes, the speaker and all the pins on my Pi work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default audio uses PWM (AFAIK pins 40,41).

It is POSSIBLE to enable PWM on header pins (which will disable headphone jack), and there are a few tutorials explaining this - mainly intended for those models without headphone jack, but will work on any Pi. Frankly there seems little point.

Enable with `dtoverlay audremap`:-

```
Name:   audremap

Info:   Switches PWM sound output to GPIOs on the 40-pin header

Usage:  dtoverlay=audremap,<param>=<val>

Params: swap_lr                 Reverse the channel allocation, which will also
                                swap the audio jack outputs (default off)
        enable_jack             Don't switch off the audio jack output. Does
                                nothing on BCM2711 (default off)
        pins_12_13              Select GPIOs 12 & 13 (default)
        pins_18_19              Select GPIOs 18 & 19
        pins_40_41              Select GPIOs 40 & 41
        pins_40_45              Select GPIOs 40 & 45 (don't use on BCM2711 - the
                                pins are on different controllers)
```

**BUT** you will have to supply the filtering circuitry (explained in tutorials)

NOTE this will generate line level output; it **won't** drive a speaker.

Comment: You sure? I added `dtoverlay=audremap,pins_18_19` and it started driving the speaker just fine.

Comment: It depends on the (unspecified) "speaker". A typical loudspeaker is low impedance and will produce almost inaudible sounds and will place a DC load which will overload the GPIO. It may work for a high impedance headphone.

Comment: It appears to work really well on my iMac G3 speakers. It's just a little quiet even on max volume. But other than that it's 100% usable.